# How to clear specific text with App.ClearText in Xamarin.UITest

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.uitest

I want to remove some specific text from Entry control with App.ClearText.I have created test suite with Xamarin.UITest for Entry control so i need to do this behavior.How to achieve this?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I may have a workaround for you. Try using a method like this:

```
private void RemoveSpecificText(string uiControlAccessibilityLabel, string textFragmentToRemove)
{
  string text = app.Query(c => c.Marked(uiControlAccessibilityLabel)).First().Text;
  app.ClearText(c => c.Marked(uiControlAccessibilityLabel));
  text = text.Replace(textFragmentToRemove, "");
  app.EnterText(c => c.Marked(uiControlAccessibilityLabel), text);
}
```

That will extract the text from the control, remove the specified text and put it back.

So, you would have to call it like this:

```
RemoveSpecificText("textFieldId", "Entry");
```